# Iterate javascript array and sum attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, array-algorithms

Consider an array that contains objects. Each object of the array is composed of both `label` and `value` attributes. I want to be able to compare each object of the array, and if the labels are the same, sum their values so as the labels do not repeat and have the sum of all previous values.

Like, for instance, if the array was this:

```
[{
  label: "A",
  value: 10
  }, {
  label: "B",
  value: 20
  }, {
  label: "C",
  value: 30
  }, {
  label: "C",
  value: 40
  }, {
  label: "D",
  value: 12
  }, {
  label: "D",
  value: 23
}]
```

In the end I would have the array with only four labels (A, B, C, D) and the value 10 for A, 20 for B, 70 for C and 35 for D.

I tried using a for loop:

```
for (i = 1; i < transformation.length; i++) {
              if (transformation[i-1].label == transformation[i].label) {
                result.label.push = transformation[i].label;
                result.value.push = transformation[i-1].value + transformation[i].value;

              }
            };
```

But I got stuck here and have no ideas on how to deal with non repeated values.
I need the final array to still be an array, not an object.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect case for `Array.reduce`!

```
var sums = arr.reduce(function(results, item) {
    if (!results.hasOwnProperty(item.label)) {
        results[item.label] = 0;
    }

    results[item.label] += item.value;
    return results;
}, {});

console.log(sums); //Object {A: 10, B: 20, C: 70, D: 35}
```

`results` will contain 4 keys A,B,C,D, each containing the total of times it occurred in the array.

Comment: A subsequent `Object.entries(sums).map(a => ({label: a[0], value: a[1]}));` would create an array with object like `{label: "X", value: y}`.

Comment: @tymeJV This does not fully work since I can't use the `.map` function on the result and I do need it. It returns an object instead of returning an array.

Comment: @Xufox my console says `Object.entries` is not a function

Comment: @Shoplifter.Doe Well, look at the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility) of that function. It’s supported almost nowhere. But still, it _would_ solve your problem.

Comment: @Xufox Yes it would. I remember now I tried to use it some time ago. Isn't there another way to get the result as an array instead of an object?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Array.reduce`

Same as @tymeJV, but as a one-liner

```
var sum = transformation.reduce(function(sumAll, item) {
  sumAll[item.label] = item.value + sumAll[item.label] || 0;
  return sumAll;
}, {})

console.log(sum) // {"A":10,"B":20,"C":70,"D":35}
```